# Can't see * in shell variable shows files in folder

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, variables, unix

Content of my file named /tmp/tmp.txt is

```
Allow
- 's3:GetObject'
arn:aws:s3::*:${dtddyuffjf}/*
Allow
- 'SQS:GetMessage'
${DocServiceQueue.Arn}
Allow
- ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
- ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
- ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
*
```

I am passing this to a variable like below
v1=  $(cat /tmp/tmp.txt)

echo $v1 showing

Allow

- 's3:GetObject'
  arn:aws:s3::*:${dtddyuffjf}/*
  Allow
- 'SQS:GetMessage'
  ${DocServiceQueue.Arn}
  Allow
- ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
- ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
- ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
  and instead of the * , it's showing content of the folder
  It does not show *

Comment: Yes it resolves my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try echo with double quotes:

```
echo "$v1"
```

`echo *` is equivalent to `ls`. The shell will treat it as 'ls' command and will list the files in that directory.

Just for your reference try running below:

```
echo *
```

and

```
echo "*"
```

Comment: See the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly including the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".

Comment: (and no, `echo *` and `ls` do not have identical behavior; both are rather poorly defined, but `echo *` is considerably less reliable -- see the APPLICATION USAGE section of the [POSIX `echo` specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), keeping in mind that filenames are effectively undefined -- they _can_ contain backslash escape sequences, names like `-n`, etc).